# SQL query performance for a 'map' statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know what is the performance difference for these query statements:

```
# Case 1
accounts = ids.map { |id| Account.find_by_id(id) }

# Case 2
accounts = ids.map { |id| Account.where(:id => id).first }
```

**There is another way to do things better?** *If `ids` are 100*, **how can I limit the search until accounts are 5?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @RubyFanatic said, there's no real difference between those two (they'd both generate the same query), but there is a considerably better way of doing it:

```
accounts = Account.where(:id => ids)
```

This will generate sql like `select * from accounts where accounts.id in (1,2,3)` and will be considerably faster than finding them one at a time.

And if you want to only use say 5 of the ids from the array of ids, you'd need to decide which 5 to use. For example, if you wanted to use the first 5;

```
accounts = Account.where(:id => ids[0..4])
```

Or, you could use limit, but this makes the query have to do a little more work still if the ids array is large:

```
accounts = Account.where(:id => ids).limit(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be no performance difference for these two queries. They are literally doing the same thing. The second statement might be slightly slower but it's so minuscule that it does not even matter.